# HTML - Registration bar & text color

Tags: html, colors

I am currently creating a website, and I am working on the registration form. 
However, when I try to set color for the text and the bar itself, it doesn't make any changes. This is the code I wrote (I erased the color for bar):

```
<form>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td style=color:"#10F5F0;"> Name:</td>
  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name=""> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Email: </td>
  <td> <input type="mail" placeholder="Email" email=""> </td>
</tr>
```

Do you know a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Do `style="color:#10F5F0;"` instead of  `style=color:"#10F5F0;"`(notice the `"`)

Comment: <td ><span style=color:"#10F5F0;"> Name :</span></td>

Answer (score 1):

Looking like invalid CSS syntax in HTML code, the color hax code is using without quotation in CSS, the CSS properties should wrap by Quotation marks (") in inline CSS

```html
<form>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td style=color:#10F5F0;> Name:</td>
  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name=""> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Email: </td>
  <td> <input type="mail" placeholder="Email" email=""> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but i think you helping him even more if you try to explain what you did different

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow,

The error you have is that you don't include color in your quotes "", its a typo. However you can try, `style="color:#10F5F0;"`

You can add `!important;` at the end of your css. This will override anything that causes you the problems.

For Example: -->

```
   #red{
    color:red !important;
    }
```

I hope this could help.